# Cordova plugin installation with plugman fails

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins, cordova-plugins, plugman

Following the phonegap tutorial [1], I'm trying to install a cordova plugin (using the latest **plugman v1.3.0** [2]). It fails with the following error:

```
C:\Android-dev\cordova-android\bin\HybridAndroidApp>plugman install --platform android --project . --plugin nl.x-services.plugins.toast
Notice: nl.x-services.plugins.toast has been automatically converted to cordova-plugin-x-toast and fetched from npm. This is due to our old plugins registry shutting down.
Fetching plugin "cordova-plugin-x-toast" via npm
Installing "cordova-plugin-x-toast" for android
Failed to install 'cordova-plugin-x-toast':TypeError: pluginInfo.getEditConfigs is not a function
    at PlatformMunger.add_plugin_changes (C:\Android-dev\cordova-android\bin\HybridAndroidApp\cordova\node_modules\cordova-common\src\ConfigChanges\ConfigChanges.js:134:42)
    at C:\Android-dev\cordova-android\bin\HybridAndroidApp\cordova\node_modules\cordova-common\src\PluginManager.js:126:25
    at _fulfilled (C:\Android-dev\cordova-android\bin\HybridAndroidApp\cordova\node_modules\q\q.js:834:54)
    at self.promiseDispatch.done (C:\Android-dev\cordova-android\bin\HybridAndroidApp\cordova\node_modules\q\q.js:863:30)
    at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (C:\Android-dev\cordova-android\bin\HybridAndroidApp\cordova\node_modules\q\q.js:796:13)
    at C:\Android-dev\cordova-android\bin\HybridAndroidApp\cordova\node_modules\q\q.js:857:14
    at runSingle (C:\Android-dev\cordova-android\bin\HybridAndroidApp\cordova\node_modules\q\q.js:137:13)
    at flush (C:\Android-dev\cordova-android\bin\HybridAndroidApp\cordova\node_modules\q\q.js:125:13)
    at nextTickCallbackWith0Args (node.js:420:9)
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:349:13)
pluginInfo.getEditConfigs is not a function
```

I found there was a recent issue with cordova-lib:
https://www.mail-archive.com/issues@cordova.apache.org/msg70264.html

I just installed plugman using npm. I'm lost how to continue using the fixed plugman (if it got fixed). I appreciate a lot your help.

Thanks!

[1] http://docs.phonegap.com/tutorials/develop/1-embed-webview/android/

[2] https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugman

Comment: The bug-fix is now under developement: https://forums.adobe.com/message/8937772.
We will just have to wait ...

Answer (score 0):

If anyone still getting this error, try below

```
# plugman install --platform android --project . --plugin cordova-plugin-x-toast
```

More information about this plugin you can find [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-x-toast).